# How can I access class methods with no object created in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on C# game using Windows Forms Apps and I have Form named "Game" that contains something like this (It's just a part of full code):

```
public Game()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Player p1 = new Player(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Clear();
    button1.Visible = false;
    textBox1.Visible = false;
}
private void KeyIsDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && !p1.jumping)
    {
        p1.jumping= true;
    }
}
```

and here is part of another class file named "Player.cs" (with same Namespace of course):

```
public class Player
{
    public string name;
    public int score;
    public bool jumping = false;

    public Player(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The only problem is that I can't access object "p1" (created by clicking on Button1) in another method (in this case "KeyIsDown") because "p1" doesn't exist. How can I solve that?
Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: What about puting that variable as field of the form (where averybody can reach it)? But keep the creation where it is now. Actually there are better patterns for that, but this can be a starting point.

Comment: You'll want to break out your book and read about the concept of *scope*.  Simply put where you declare a variable determines where you can use it.  Declare it in a click event and thats the only place you can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the variable you created is not global. The only thing you must do inside the fuction Button1_Click is initialize the variable like:

p1 = new Player(...);

But outside the function and inside the Game class, you must generate a variable called:

Player p1;

You MUST leave it without initialization until you press the button. Good luck.